# Recalculate coordinates for different image size

Tags: c#, math

I have a fix to complete that involves calculating points in an image that have been incorrectly calculated. I have an image and a string of coordinates that mark a region within that image. Some processing has messed up those points so that they are no longer relative to where they should be & I know how to stop that. The images are of cars and the regions highlight front wing, wheel etc.

I am pretty sure I should be able to re calculate the points for the actual image size based on some ratio but after that the maths is eluding me. Can some one either explain the maths or point me at a decent tutorial for it. Thanks.

This is the code I am trying to undo:

```
if (currentPoints.Count > 0)
{
    result = true;
    float xWidth = 1500f;
    float xHeight = 1500f;
    float ratio = xWidth / source.Width;
    xHeight = source.Height * ratio;
    if (source.LeftExtent > 0 || source.RightExtent > 0)
    {
        if (source.RightExtent > source.LeftExtent)
        {
            result = false;
            xWidth = source.RightExtent - source.LeftExtent;
        }
    }
    if (source.TopExtent > 0 || source.BottomExtent > 0)
    {
       if (source.BottomExtent > source.TopExtent)
       {
           result = false;
           xHeight = source.BottomExtent - source.TopExtent;
       }
    }

    float xRatio = iWidth / xWidth; 
    float yRatio = iHeight / xHeight;
    List<Point> newPoints = new List<Point>();
    foreach (Point cPoint in currentPoints)
    {
        globals.log.Information("Calculating new coordinates for point: {@cPoint}", cPoint);
        double newX = (cPoint.X - source.LeftExtent) * xRatio;
        double newY = (cPoint.Y - source.TopExtent) * yRatio;
        Point newPoint = new Point(newX, newY);
        globals.log.Information(
                                "New Point calculated: {@newPoint} using x =  ({cPoint.X} - {source.LeftExtent}) x {xRatio}, y =  ({cPoint.Y} - {source.TopExtent}) x {yRatio}",
        newPoint, cPoint.X, source.LeftExtent, xRatio, cPoint.Y, source.TopExtent, yRatio);
        newPoints.Add(newPoint);
   }
```

The image after running through the above looks something like:
[image]

& my latest attempt to fix is:

```
public class EntryPoint
    {
        private readonly ILogger<EntryPoint> logger;
        private readonly APIdeconContext context;

        public EntryPoint(ILogger<EntryPoint> logger, APIdeconContext context)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
            this.context = context;
        }

        public void Run(String[] args)
        {
            var images = context.Images.Where(i => i.ModelId == 3).ToList();

            foreach(var image in images)
            {
                var mappings = context.Mappings.Where(m => m.ImageId == image.ImageId).ToList();
                var mappingDims = discoverMappingExtents(mappings);

                foreach(var mapping in mappings)
                {
                    CalcNewPoints(image, mapping, mappingDims);
                }
            }

        }

        private MappingDimension discoverMappingExtents(List<Mapping> mappings)
        {
            double left = double.MaxValue;
            double right = double.MinValue;
            double top = double.MaxValue;
            double bottom = double.MinValue;

            foreach(var mapping in mappings)
            {
                var coords = mapping.CoOrdinates.Split(' ');
                foreach(var pair in coords)
                {
                    var coord = pair.Split(',');
                    double xPos = 0f;
                    double yPos = 0f;
                    double.TryParse(coord[0], out xPos);
                    double.TryParse(coord[1], out yPos);

                    if(xPos < left)
                    {
                        left = xPos;
                    }
                    else if(xPos > right)
                    {
                        right = xPos;
                    }

                    if(yPos < top)
                    {
                        top = yPos;
                    }
                    else if(yPos > bottom)
                    {
                        bottom = yPos;
                    }
                }
            }

            return new MappingDimension{Left = left, Right = right, Top = top, Bottom = bottom};
        }

        private string CalcNewPoints(Image image, Mapping mapping, MappingDimension source)
        {
            var coordBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            var coords = mapping.CoOrdinates.Split(' ');

            double xRatio = source.Width / image.Width;
            double yRatio = source.Height / image.Height;
            foreach(string pair in coords)
            {
                if(pair.Contains(','))
                {
                    string[] coord = pair.Split(',');
                    double xPos = 0f;
                    double yPos = 0f;
                    double.TryParse(coord[0], out xPos);
                    double.TryParse(coord[1], out yPos);

                    double newX = (xPos - source.Left) * xRatio;
                    double newY = (yPos - source.Top) * yRatio;

                   coordBuilder.Append($"{newX},{newY} ");
                }
            }

            return coordBuilder.ToString().Trim();
        }
    }

    public class MappingDimension
    {
        public double Left { get; set; }
        public double Right { get; set; }
        public double Top { get; set; }
        public double Bottom { get; set; }

        public double Width 
        { 
            get
            {
                return Right - Left;
            }
        }
        public double Height 
        { 
            get
            {
                return Bottom - Top;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question doesn't provide an example image / points as well as an explanation of how these points are generated. Your question has the c# tag - so where's the c# code ?

Comment: "Wrong Points" in the sense of coordinates are based on original image size, but it has been resized since? If so, was cropping involved or just stretching/shrinking?

Comment: @auburg Updated with more info.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/982149/fildor The image size is the same but it has run through the alteration code in error maybe multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to translate from one range of values to another is

```
 toMin + ((toMax - toMin) / (fromMax - fromMin)) * (value - fromMin);
```

I.e. start by subtracting the offset used for the from-range, multiply by the relative scale, and add the to-offset. For images, offset, i.e. fromMin/toMin is zero, unless the images have different positions, and the fromMax/toMax would be the respective image size.

Do the same calculation for x and y coordinates and you can rescale your points.

Comment: Am I right in assuming value is the x/y value? I am off to attempt that.

Comment: @onesixtyfourth Yes, `value` would be the x/y value you need to scale.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't seem to get that to work & I don't think I am trying to do a straight rescale in that way as I don't really have a from image. My from are mappings into the image that have got screwed up somehow. I may not have the data to put it back as I think I should be able to.

Comment: @onesixtyfourth you will need some way to find the transform/scale. For example by finding the "correct" coordinates of two points somehow. If you have that you can use the formula above to apply correct all points. Just use the incorrect coordinates as the "to" fields, the corrected as the "from".

Comment: Would the set of mappings give me the from size? I have been attempting this for one mapping and obvs I need to adjust that way but the set of mappings should give me width & height values to calc from. What do you think. The blueish area in the image above would be the set.

Comment: Still having a bit of trouble with the above calculation but I now have the width & height of the set of mappings.

start by subtracting the offset for the from - I have an object that holds the left, right, top & bottom values in the extreme i.e. each is the lowest/highest for that axis.

Multiply by the relative scale - divide source by target image where source gives width = right - left etc

Add the to offset - I am removing left/top from the x/y positions.

Its close but no cigar, I will update the main bit with latest code.

Comment: @onesixtyfourth your example code is unnecessarily complicated to read since it mixes things like parsing coordinates with actual calculations. Good practice would be to parse values *once* when they are loaded, and use some kind of vector2 type for the coordinates. As far as I can see the example code uses the point-bounds and image bounds for the mapping. That is probably not correct, i.e. it should either be two image bounds, or two point-bounds.

Comment: Thank you @JonasH this got me along way. I have not solved this yet but that is because I have since discovered my problem is quite different to what I explained above. Thank you and the code you provided did at least get me some way down the path I need to be on.